# If $\frac{dp}{dt}=0.2p(500-p)$ and $p(0)=105$, what value does $p$ approach as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Problem**

I am currently working on the following differential equations problem.

> If $\frac{dp}{dt}=0.2p(500-p)$ and $p(0)=105$, what does $p$ approach
>   as $t\rightarrow \infty$?

However, there *is* a catch -- I am not allowed to solve this differential equation, and must give some other justification behind my answer.

---

**My Question**

Clearly $p=0$ and $p=500$ are the critical points of $\frac{dp}{dt}$.  However without being able to solve this equation I am unsure how to conclude what $p$ approaches.  Any hints?  I've searched through the textbook assuming there must be *something* I am missing, but everytime the text handles these problems they usually solve the differential equation.  Am I just overthinking this problem?

---

**Thanks!**

Comment: Are you learning about direction fields?

Comment: the searched Limit must be $$500$$

Comment: As @Moo said, you are considering the solution of $p'(t)=f(p(t))$ for some function $f$ positive on $(a,b)$ with $f(b)=0$, for $p(0)$ in $(a,b)$. Then **it is a result in your notes** that $p(t)\to b$ when $t\to\infty$.

Comment: I don't understand the down-votes. This is a very good question over a topic with which many early calculus students struggle, and the OP has clearly put thought and care into the post.

Comment: Sorry guys, I just finally got a chance to check this!  Thank you ALL for your help on this.  We did learn about direction fields recently and I think I understand where my confusion was now that @ChaseRyanTaylor provided the wonderful answer below.

Comment: @ThyArtisMath $$\Huge\ddot\smile$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a logistic differential equations. A **logistic differential equation** is of the form

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky\left( 1-\frac{y}{L}\right)$$

where $y$ is the dependent variable, $t$ is the independent variable, and $k$ and $L$ are constants.

Notice that as $y\to L$, the growth rate approaches $0$. (If $k$ is negative, then this is actually a decay rate.) This means that as $t\to\infty$, $y$ grows more and more slowly, and $y$ is never able to surpass $L$. Thus,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}y=L$$

Functions of this form are often used to model the growth of populations in an environment that has a finite carrying capacity. If you’re curious, at any given point, the percentage of growth that remains for $y$ equals $1-y/L$.

[image: photo]

You can answer your question by doing some algebra to get $p$ in the form that features $L$ and then invoking the logic I modeled above.

> Alternatively, you could note that as $p\to500$, the quantity $(500-p)\to0$, which brings $dp/dt\to0$ and prevents $p$ from passing $500$. I usually recommend the prior approach I mentioned, because students seem to remember it better.

Comment: Thank you for this very clear and thoughtful answer, as well as saving me from the downvotes.  I can't say I understand why the question was being voted down, but that is irrelevant now.  Cheers!

Comment: @ThyArtisMath Cheers!